# min value for each combination using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
col1    col2   col3 
 A       B       4
 A       B       1
 A       C       2
 P       B       2
 P       D       7
 P       D       3
```

I want the minimum value of col3 for each combination of col1 and col2. The output will be like:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
 A       B       1
 A       C       2
 P       B       2
 P       D       3
```

I have tried the code

```
df.groupby(['Col3']).min()
```

But It's not giving expected result. How to do this in efficient way ?

Comment: `df.groupby(['col1','col2'],as_index=False).min()
` or`df.sort_values('col3').drop_duplicated(['col1','col2'],keep='last')`

Comment: @Wen, Feel free to reopen this one to explain the 2 options. I know there's a better dup target but I can't find it :(

Comment: @jpp this must be a dup , I agree with you , just too lazy to find a dup  . haha :-)

Comment: `df['col3'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform('min')`, followed by `df = df.drop_duplicates()`